# HIve join without common filed

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have the following tables:

`Table1`:

```
user_name Url
Rahul    www.cric.info.com
ranbir   www.rogby.com
sahil    www.google.com
banit    www.yahoo.com
```

`Table2`:

```
Keyword  category
cric     sports
footbal sports
google  search
```

I want to search `Table1` by matching the keyword in `Table2`. I can perform the same using case statement and the query works but it is not the right approach because each time I have to add the case statement when I will add new search keyword.

```
select user_name from table1
case when url like '%cric%' then sports
else 'undefined'
end as category 
from table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks find the soluntions for this approach. FIrst we need to do the Join and after that we need to filter the record.

```
select user_name,url,Keyword,catagory from(select table1.user_name,table1.url ,table2.keyword,table2.catagory from table1 left outer join table2)a where a.url like (concat('%',a.phrase,'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about more current versions, but I've run into a similar problem... the primary issue is that Hive only supports equi-join statements... when you apply logic to either side of the join, it has difficulty translating into a Map Reduce function.

The alternative method, if you have a reliably structured field, is that you can create a matching key from the larger field.  For example, if you know that you're looking for your keyword to exist in the second position of a dot-delimited URI, you could do something like:

```
select
Uri
, split(Uri, "\\.")[1] as matchKey
from
Table1
join Table2 on Table2.keyword = Table1.matchKey
;
```